# Dynamic Remote Url for webpack Module Federation

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, webpack-module-federation, craco

Assuming that both my remote and consumer application is hosted on the same domain and that domain might change dynamically based on deployment box, what would be best practice to give remote url in webpack module federation.

```
{
remotes: {
    app1: 'app1@https://domain.100.com/remoteEntry.js',
  },
  remoteType:'script',
  filename: "remoteEntry.js",
  shared: {
    react: {
      eager: true,
      singleton: true,
      requiredVersion: deps["react"],
    },
    "react-dom": {
      eager: true,
      singleton: true,
      requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
    },
  }
}
```

Here the app1 could be loaded from `https://domain.101.com` as well. In that case the consumer application is also hosted at `https://domain.101.com`